# Interpolating DataArray to New Coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I’m trying to interpolate a larger dataset onto the coordinates of another so that I can do computations with them. I’ve used .interp before but it seems to fail since the dimensions seem to be indexed by x,y and not lat,lon. How could that be fixed so I could interpolated the data?

```
lons, lats = precip_data.lon, precip_data.lat
temperature_interp = temperature_data.interp(latitude=lats, longitude=lons)
```

Throws the error:

```
ValueError: dimensions {'longitude', 'latitude'} do not exist
```

*Precipitation DataArray*

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PRECIP' (y: 235, x: 180)>
array([[0.      , 0.      , 0.      , ..., 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ],
       [0.      , 0.      , 0.      , ..., 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ],
       [0.      , 0.      , 0.      , ..., 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ],
       ...,
       [0.      , 0.      , 0.      , ..., 0.014764, 0.014764, 0.014764],
       [0.      , 0.      , 0.      , ..., 0.014764, 0.014764, 0.014764],
       [0.      , 0.      , 0.      , ..., 0.014764, 0.019685, 0.014764]],
      dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    time     datetime64[ns] 2020-02-28
  * y        (y) float64 -4.791e+06 -4.786e+06 ... -3.681e+06 -3.677e+06
  * x        (x) float64 2.234e+06 2.238e+06 2.243e+06 ... 3.081e+06 3.086e+06
    lat      (y, x) float64 ...
    lon      (y, x) float64 ...
Attributes:
    long_name:     PRECIP
    units:         IN
    grid_mapping:  crs
```

*Temperature DataArray*

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (x: 451, y: 337)
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] ...
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
    latitude    (y, x) float64 ...
    longitude   (y, x) float64 ...
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    t           (y, x) float32 294.39157 294.39157 ... 259.6211 259.6211
```

Comment: Have you tried with `temperature_interp = temperature_data.interp(x=lats, y=lons)`?

Comment: It works but returns only NaN values